# Could not find class in Junit-4.11

Tags: java, junit

I configured Junit-4.11 on my Mac, compile with `javac` has no error, but when I run with `java`, I got `Could not find class: HelloWorldTest`

Here is my `HelloWorld.java` and `HelloWorldTest.java`

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public String output() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.*;
import org.junit.*;

public class HelloWorldTest {
    public HelloWorld helloworld = new HelloWorld();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void oneTimeSetUp() {
        System.out.println("@BeforeClass - oneTimeSetUp");
    }
    @AfterClass
    public static void oneTimeTearDown() {
        System.out.println("@AfterClass - oneTimeTearDown");
    }
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.out.println("@Before - setUp");
    }
    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("@After - tearDown");
    }
    @Test
    public void testOutput() {
        assertEquals(helloworld.output(), "Hello world!");
        System.out.println("@Test - testOutput");
    }
}
```

And I run with

`javac -classpath ./ HelloWorldTest.java`

and `java -classpath ./ org.junit.runner.JUnitCore HelloWorldTest`

What I got is

```
JUnit version 4.11
Could not find class: HelloWorldTest

Time: 0.002

OK (0 tests)
```

I put `junit-4.11.jar` in the current directory with `HelloWorld.java` and `HelloWorldTest.java`, I also put it in /Library/Java/Extensions

What I tried to solve is to set `JAVA_HOME` and `CLASSPATH`, but it did not work.

Could someone point out what was going wrong? I was really confused.

Thankyou.

Well I have solved my problem with the following steps. My Mac is Mac OSX 10.8 and I used JVM-1.6 provided by Apple. You can download it by clicking [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572).

1. Delete the `CLASSPATH` in my `.zshrc` file(If you are using `Bash` I think it is `.bashrc`)
2. Delete the `JUnit-4.11.jar`(or any version you use) in the `/Library/Java/Extensions` and any System Directory you put it in.
3. Try to compile again and run it.

And I set `JAVA_HOME` as `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home`

Thank you.

Comment: CLASS_PATH does not hold any meaning in Java, I guess you mean CLASSPATH

Comment: Consider using Maven or Gradle for your builds.

Comment: sorry, my fault, I corrected it. @HimanshuBhardwaj

Comment: Thanks to your question I managed to solve my problem but one thing which I don't understand is that why do we have to associate the hamcrest libraries into the testing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update**: The original poster's solution is buried in a comment below. It has to do with not having the junit jar files in `/Library/Java/Extensions`, and not having a `CLASSPATH`:

> I deleted CLASSPATH in my .zshrc file, and I also deleted
>   junit-4.11.jar in /Library/Java/Extensions and
>   /Library/Java/Home/lib/ext, and then JUnit-4.11 worked.

---

In a temp dir (java files from your question):

```
HelloWorld.java
HelloWorldTest.java
junit-4.11.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
```

Then:

- `javac -cp junit-4.11.jar *.java`
- `java -cp junit-4.11.jar:hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore HelloWorldTest`

Output:

```
HelloWorldTest
JUnit version 4.11
@BeforeClass - oneTimeSetUp
.@Before - setUp
@Test - testOutput
@After - tearDown
@AfterClass - oneTimeTearDown

Time: 0,004

OK (1 test)
```

**I would advise retrying from scratch**

Comment: Still I got could not find class, is there anything else I should pay attention to? Thankyou.

Comment: Check if both .java have a compiled .class, check your java version

Comment: Thankyou, both .java have a compiled .class, and java version is 1.7.0_25

Comment: Still a "works for me" on OSX 10.8.4 / java 1.6.0_51. You should try with apple provided JVM (i.e. 1.6)

Comment: Thank you very much. You think it is because of the version of JVM?

Comment: I tried java 1.6.0_51, which is provied by Apple. But still I got the problem, do you know the value of `JAVA_HOME` and `CLASSPATH`? I set `JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home` and `CLASSPATH=/Library/Java/Extensions` and `CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:.`.   Are these right?  Thank you.

Comment: I change JUnit to 4.10 and it works. I don't know why, I will try later and I will tell you if I find something useful. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I found the difference. I deleted `CLASSPATH` in my `.zshrc` file, and I also deleted `junit-4.11.jar` in `/Library/Java/Extensions` and `/Library/Java/Home/lib/ext`, and then `JUnit-4.11` worked. Thank you for your help again. I will update my problem.

Comment: I had the same problem when I had `junit-4.11.jar` in `/Library/Java/Extensions/`. When I moved the jar file elsewhere, things worked as expected.

Comment: @Poulsbo So where should the `junit.jar` file be moved to?

Comment: @dee It's been awhile but I think what I meant is that I moved it out of any `CLASSPATH` directories. You could try renaming your `junit.jar` file to something like `junit.jar.HIDE`. If things work after doing that, you can then delete the file.

Comment: replace the ":" in classpath with ";" is work for me

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tested the same. Will provide the steps for the same:

```
/
|
|--HelloWorld.java
|--HelloWorldTest.java
```

First process **HelloWorld.java**:

```
javac HelloWorld.java
```

This will result in HelloWorld.class in the same folder.

Next process **HelloWorldTest.java**:

```
javac -classpath C:\Himanshu_Work\repo\junit\junit\4.10\junit-4.10.jar;. HelloWorldTest.java
```

This will result in **HelloWorldTest.class** in the same folder.

```
java -classpath C:\Himanshu_Work\repo\junit\junit\4.10\junit-4.10.jar;. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore  HelloWorldTest
JUnit version 4.10
@BeforeClass - oneTimeSetUp
.@Before - setUp
@Test - testOutput
@After - tearDown
@AfterClass - oneTimeTearDown

Time: 0

OK (1 test)
```

Comment: I still have the problem under Mac OSX 10.8, but thankyou very much.

Comment: Is the folder containing HelloWorldTest.class file after running javac command for HelloWorldTest.java

Comment: Yes. All the file after running `javac` are in the current folder.

Comment: I don't have MAC OS to test, but the standard rules apply. So this should be fine... Did you try doing a java command for HelloWorld with same arguments to see if it is detecting the HelloWorld class file. Also replace ./ with . in -classpath param